# Remove context name from URL - mod_proxy_ajp with Spring Security

Tags: spring, security, url, proxy, ajp

I have a app named "FitnessTracker" running on tomcat, post 8080. I am using Spring Security, and everything works fine when I test it directly on tomcat using `http://localhost:8080/FitnessTracker`

I then configured mod_proxy_ajp on Apache http 2.2, to access using a domain name, below is my VirtualHost configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.testing.com
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    RewriteEngine on 
    RewriteRule ^/FitnessTracker/(.*)$ /$1 [P]

    ProxyPass /  ajp://localhost:8009/FitnessTracker/
    ProxyPassReverse / ajp://localhost:8009/FitnessTracker/
</VirtualHost>
```

Now, when I access www.testing.com/ - it gets redirected to www.testing.com/FitnessTracker/login.html

Is there a way to not have ***/FitnessTracker/*** in the URL? I would like to hide the tomcat Context name from the URL.
Ideally, I want the URL to look like **www.testing.com/login.html** 
I know that this is due to the RewriteRule, but without the rewrite rule spring security with mod_proxy doesn't work - since Spring security redirects to login page along with context name.

Please let me know if you have suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you forgot to rewrite the cookie domain and cookie path. Check `ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain` directive. From the backend perspective the request path still has to look like `/FitnessTracker/`

Comment: I was looking at way to have app accessible without having to have context name in the URL

Comment: Please read http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassreverse